# CSS Grid auto-wrap aside when it gets to a certain size

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

So I am creating a layout where I have a

```
<div id="structure-content">
<main>content goes here</main>
<aside>aside content</aside>
</div>
```

I want the aside to be a quarter of the width and to automatically wrap to below the main once it hits a certain size and the main to take the full width. I know I can do this with media queries but people are saying that it can be done with grid and no media queries. I have been experimenting and researching for hours and cannot work it out. Any ideas? If it cannot be done then that is fine and I can try it with flexbox or media queries.

Props in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CSS Grid, you can make the `main` and `aside` to take *half of the available width* and *auto-wrap* when either of the grid item hit a *minimum* width using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr))` - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#structure-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}
main {
  background: aliceblue;
}
aside {
  background: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="structure-content">
  <main>content goes here</main>
  <aside>aside content</aside>
</div>
```

---

**Solution**

With CSS Grid, I'd say you can go with *media queries*. Anyway a *flexbox* will work here nice:

- use a *wrapping* flexbox
- keep a `min-width` for each of `aside` and `main` and add `flex: 1` to *flex it to the remaining space if available* - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#structure-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* a wrapping flexbox */
}
main {
  background: aliceblue;
  min-width: 75vw; /* forces aside to take one-fourth space */
  flex: 1;
}
aside {
  background: cadetblue;
  min-width: 250px; /* minimum width of aside */
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="structure-content">
  <main>content goes here</main>
  <aside>aside content</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. It appears that I could almost get it all working and probably I will work it out with a bit more tinkering. As it is, your code snippet verified a few thoughts that I had with the approach I was taking. Appreciate your time and insight.

Answer (score 5):

The below code the div reach certain size will goes down automatically. If you want to drop the div particular size we have to use media query only.

```css
#structure-content {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    background: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1.5em 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

main {
    background: green;
}

aside {
    background: blue;
}

main,
aside {
    flex: 1 0 15em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="structure-content">
    <main>content goes here</main>
    <aside>aside content</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I mentioned above, I need the columns to be different widths. Your code did give me some ideas though. Cheers.